# Relative homology of disconnection (if $X=A\cup B$, then $H_n(X,A)\cong H_n(B)$ for all $n$)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

From Rotman's book on algebraic topology (Exercise 6.2):

> If $X=A\cup B$ is a disconnection (i.e., $A$ and $B$ are nonempty open sets with empty intersection), then $H_n(X,A)\cong H_n(B)$ for all $n\ge0$.

I think this should probably use the previous exercise, which used Mayer-Vietoris to show that $H_n(X)=H_n(A)\oplus H_n(B)$, but since I can't actually "divide" both sides by $H_n(A)$, I'm not sure how to continue.

I also thought about using the long exact sequence for relative homology. However, I was unable to bring $B$ into this sequence.

Finally, I thought about going back to the definitions of $H_n$ as $\ker\partial_n/\text{im}~\partial_{n+1}$. But this seemed a bit messy so, if I'm being honest, I didn't really pursue this track any further.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? (Given that this exercise appears in Chapter 6, I feel like it should use Mayer-Vietoris or excision, and would like to find a solution using one of those techniques, if possible; but of course any hints are appreciated.)

Comment: Think about what the relative chain complex $C_*(X,A)$ is, in concrete terms.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the long exact sequence for relative homology.  To bring $B$ into it, you can use the isomorphism $H_n(X)\cong H_n(A)\oplus H_n(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the excision axiom: Excise $A$ (which is possible because $\bar A = A \subset A = \text{int}(A)$ to get
$$H_n(X,A) \approx H_n(X \setminus A, A \setminus A) = H_n(B,\emptyset) = H_n(B).$$